# Is the Oly 25mm/1.8 too large for the built-in flash of the OM-D E-M10 Mark II

Tags: olympus

I am thinking of buying a Olympus OM-D E-M10 Mark II as a point and shoot alternative. I think the Olympus M.ZUIKO DIGITAL 25mm 1:1.8 is a better alternative than the kit lense. Somebody who owns these can confirm whether the built in flash is usable in this combination? (Does not throw shadows because of the size of the lense)

Comment: Please make your title reflect the question, not just mention part of it. Thanks!

Comment: Using a lens hood may affect this.

Answer (score 1):

I got really curious and tried it with my Panasonic 25mm f1.7, which is actually bigger than the Olympus 25 f1.8.

[image: 1m against the wall, I think 1/4 power]
[image: .5m against the wall, I think 1/8 power]

I didn't see any shadows from the flash.

I doubt if that would be a problem for a first party lense.

Comment: Does that dark spot just to the right of center occur in all your photos, or is that a low-iillumination area from your flash?

Comment: @scottbb Fabric stain?

Comment: Stain on the hotel wall

Comment: Ah. I shouldn’t have forgotten Occam’s rule for debugging and diagnosis: “When you hear hooves, think horses, not zebras” :)

Comment: Corollary: “... unless you’re in the Serengeti”